# R Shiny check total upload size

Tags: r, memory, shiny, server, upload

Shiny lets you specify a maximum file size with `options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 1000*1024^2)`. How do I set a limit on the total size when uploading multiple files with `fileInput(multiple = TRUE)`? I.e., the sum of the selected files must be smaller than X MB?

Comment: maxRequestSize works per file, so multiple = TRUE would not affect the performance

Comment: I want to the set a limit on the sum of all the files, not per file